# Poisson Process Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

Given $X_t$ a Poisson process such that $\lambda = 1$ find $E[X_1\mid X_2]$ and $E[X_2\mid X_1]$.

The first one is pretty straight forward since we have $E[X_2 - X_1] = E[X_1] = 1$ so then we get $E[X_2 \mid X_1] = E[X_2 - X_1 + X_1 \mid X_1] = E[X_2 - X_1 \mid X_1] + E[X_1\mid X_1] = 1+ X_1$ as $X_2-X_1$ is independent of $X_1$.

As for $E[X_1\mid X_2]$ I'm not entrirely sure, I already know the answer should be $\frac{X_2}{2}$ but that is not what I am getting. It relates to binomial if I understand correctly.

I believe I should have $$P(X_1\mid X_2) = \frac{P(X_1 = x, X_2 = y)}{P(X_2 = y)} = \frac{P(X_1 = x, X_2 - X_1 = y-x)}{P(X_2 = y)}  = \frac{P(X_1= x)P(X_2 - X_1 = y-x)}{P(X_2 = y) } = \frac{e^{-1}(x!)^{-1}e^{-1}((y-x)!)^{-1}}{e^{-2}(2^{y}/y!)} = \frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!}2^{-y}$$ but Im missing the $2^{-(y-x)}$.

Maybe I made a mistake in my conditional probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you calculated, the PMF of $X_1$ conditional on $X_2 =y$ is that of a $\mathrm{Bin}(y,1/2)$ random variable. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[X_1\mid X_2 = y] = y/2$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1\mid X_2] = X_2/2$.

Comment: I understand that, I am just not sure why when I write out the conditional probability it isn't coming out nicely as such.

Comment: It came out as $\frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!}2^{-y}= \binom{y}{x}/2^y$. Isn't that fine (since it's just the PMF of a $\mathrm{Bin}(y,1/2)$ random variable)?

Comment: that not the exact pmf of binomial though. it should be $\binom{y}{x}2^{-y}2^{-(y-x)}$.

Comment: The version with the $2^{-(y-x)}$ would be $\binom{y}{x} 2^{-\color{red}{x}}2^{-(y-x)}$ (note $x$ is the "variable" of the PMF).

Comment: oh yes you are correct, as $2^{-x}2^{-(y-x) } = 2^{-y}$. My mistake, it is always the simple arithmetic haha.